# Python word search in a text file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file in which I need to search for specific 3 words using Python. For example the words are account, online and offer and I need the count of how many times it appears in the system.

Comment: You can read the content of the text file and then use regular expressions to count the times the words you want appear

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('fixtures/file1.csv') as f:
    print len(filter(
        lambda line: "account" in line or "online" in line or "offer" in line,
        f.readlines()
    ))
```

You can also check directly if the words are in the each line.

**Update**

To count how many times does each word appear in a file, the most effective way I find is to iterate once over the file and check how many times each word is found in the line. For that, try the following:

```
keys = ('account', 'online', 'offer')

with open('fixtures/file1.csv') as f:
    found = dict((k, 0) for k in keys)

    for line in f.readlines():
        for k in keys:
            found[k] += 1 if k in line else 0
```

`found` will then be a dictionary with what you are looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The code above is working, but it combines the count of 3 words. I need the count of each word

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it is a plain text document. In that case you would `open('file.txt') as f` and then get every `[for] line in f` and check `if 'word' in f.lower()` and then incrament a counter accordingly (say `wordxtotal += 1`)